# C++: Comparing list of doubles with some invalid values (QNAN)

Tags: c++, list, compare, double

i need to compare two std::list < double >, but some doubles may be invalid numbers (QNAN).
If any invalid numbers are list entries the compare process won't work, because a comparison of the same invalid value will always result in 'false'.
What is the easiest and most elegant way to solve the problem?

My idea was to create copies of both lists, iterate through them and remove invalid values and then compare the remaining lists. The lists will typically have 20-50 values in them. Is there a more resource friendly way to solve it?

Comment: If you write your own comparison functor, you can make it return `(NaN == NaN) == true` (by explicitly testing for that case before passing down to `std::[cmpop]`).

Answer (score 4):

```
bool compare(float f1, float f2)
{
    return (f1 != f1 && f2 != f2)? true: f1 == f2;
}

std::list<float> l1, l2;
bool res = std::equal(l1.begin(), l1.end(), l2.begin(), compare);
```

Comment: +1 the OP could actually code `compare` method to handle NAN values.

Comment: +1, Just I'd use an explicit `isnan` over the `x!=x` - both for readability and for portability isolation to non-IEEEE-platforms (which are supposed to exist in one universe or another)